# "Secure origin" other than HTTPS?

Tags: google-chrome, security, https, google-chrome-devtools

Sometimes I see this warning in Chrome Devtools:

`You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.`

What's up with this "such as HTTPS"? Are there "secure origins" *other* than HTTPS that you can serve a website with?

I have no problem using https (I have it enabled on all the websites I'm working on). This question is purely out of curiousity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, `localhost` is a secure origin. Chrome also has a command line flag to treat specified HTTP endpoints as secure: `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://a.test,http://b.test`. So it's not *just* "HTTPS".

Longer answer: Other schemes such as `blob:`, `wss:`, and `chrome-extension:` can also be considered as secure contexts. `about:blank` is a common example that can vary, since the browser has to remember how it got there. And an `iframe` pointing at an HTTPS page, but embedded in an HTTP page, would not be secure.

To determine what the browser thinks of all this, examine the value of `window.isSecureContext`. The spec is here: https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/

This chromium page https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins gives some context and links to the spec above.

For instance, `data:` URLs are insecure but `blob:` URLs are secure.

```js
const src = "<script>document.write(isSecureContext)</scr"+"ipt>";

a.src = `data:text/html,${src}`;

b.src = URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob([src], {type:'text/html'}));
```

```html
<p>data url is insecure
<iframe id=a width=100 height=25></iframe>

<p>blob url is secure
<iframe id=b width=100 height=25></iframe>
```

Comment: Good to know about the --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure flag, I may need that at some point for testing in my local envirornment. Very informative answer, thanks. :D

Comment: --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure has no effect unless --user-data-dir is also supplied

Comment: @rwm I am able to use it WITHOUT --user-data-dir:

Answer (score 0):

I'm successfully able to bypass Chrome's requirement to use an https connection by doing the following. It's slightly different from the instructions in the links in the Accepted answer:

**Windows 10:**

- In the Taskbar, right-click "Chrome" icon > right-click "Google Chrome" >
  select "Properties"
- In the "Target:" field, add the flag AFTER the final
  quote mark, like this:

  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://yourDomain.com

(I didn't need to add other flags as indicated in another answer.)

Additional tags: Google Geolocation API bypass https